# Разместить между первым и последующими цифрами числа ноль

Tags: c++, c++11

Дано натуральное число N. Разместить между первой и последующими цифрами ноль.
Через цикл.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, d;
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
   
  cout << "Введите натуральное число: ";
  cin >> n;
  
  while(n <= 0){ 
    cout << "Введите натуральное число: ";
    cin >> n;
   }
   
   for (n; n != 0; n /= 10){
     d = n % 10;
     cout << d * 10;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: какой вы ожидаете вывод при вводе однозначного числа ? (от 1 до 10)

Comment: N любое число оно должно разбиваться на цифры и после этого между цифрами ставить 0

Comment: разбейте на цифры число 8 и поставьте между ними 0. Что должно получиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно, если я все верно понял:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n, d=1;

    do{
        cout << "Введите натуральное число: ";
        cin >> n;
    } while(n<=0);

    while(n/d > 1) d *= 10;
    for( ; d>1; n%=d, d/=10)
        cout << n/d << 0;
    cout << n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можете объяснить как это все работает? Если не сложно

Comment: @Rez сначала ищем максимальный число кратное 10 (`d`), но меньшее `n`. Затем мы выводим результат целочисленного деления `n` на этот `d`, при этом уменьшая `d` в 10 раз (для того, чтобы вывести следующую цифру числа   `n`) и само числа `n` делаем равным остатку от деления на предыдущий `d`. ( с той же целью, что и уменьшаем `d`)

Comment: @Rez https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Если надо просто вывести на экран, а не получить число - то вы делаете много лишнего. Посмотрите мой ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Так сойдет?

```
unsigned int add0(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int d = 1;
    while( n/d > 9) d*= 10;
    return (n/d)*10*d + n%d;
}
```

Через `for`...

```
while(условие) действие;
```

эквивалентно

```
for(; условие; ) действие;
```

или даже

```
for(; условие; действие);
```

Так что

```
while( n/d > 9) d*= 10;
```

эквивалентно

```
for(; n/d > 9 ; d*= 10);
```

Comment: Через for можно как-то реализовать?

Comment: @Rez `for(;n/d<9; d*=10); return (n/d)*10*d + n%d;`.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по принятому ответу, надо получить не число, как у Harry, а просто вывод на экран? тогда это делается куда проще:

```
int N;
cin >> N;
string s = to_string(N);
cout << s.substr(0,1) << "0" << s.substr(1) << endl;
```

И не надо всех этих расчетов.

Для wololo: ничуть не сложнее

```
string s = to_string(N);
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    cout << s[i] << (i == s.size()-1 ? "" : "0");
```

Comment: Автор вопроса вроде бы хочет поставить символ `0` после _каждой_ цифры числа (кроме быть может самой младшей).

Comment: @wololo 43265 - 4 - первая последующие - 3265. Между ними - 0. Значит, 403265. Между первой и последующими, а не между каждыми соседними.

Comment: 1) Код в принятом ответе ставит нули между всеми цифрами числа. 2) Из комментариев автора вопроса: `N любое число оно должно разбиваться на цифры и после этого между цифрами ставить 0`.

Comment: @wololo - см. дополнение. И только попробуйте утверждать, что число не разбивается на цифры!! :)